# depth of points in RGB using kinect driver

Tags: ros, kinect, points, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the depth values that obtain by kinect driver is actually a no. of streams that continuously changing even if kinect remain stationary can u tell me plz y is it so? secondly if i want to access the depth of particular point out of the depth of all points that is seen by kinect, how can i do it? plz guide me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69376/depth-of-points-in-rgb-using-kinect-driver/) by [fairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/5515/fairy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The kinect sensor, like all other sensors, doesn't provide perfect measure, there's a variation in the depth but it shouldn't be too large.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor

Regarding the depth of a particular point, you should do some point cloud tutorials so you can understand the meaning of the data you are receiving. For each point you can obtain the x, y and z coordinates in the frame of the camera.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2013-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fairy](https://answers.ros.org/users/5515/fairy/) on 2013-07-30**:
thanks  for the answer, but can I retrieve depth of particular point without going in to pcl? by making use of opencv function cvGet2D in order to access the intensity of particular point